# Why doesn't WScript.Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings work with %CD%?

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, wsh

In the command line you can output the current directory using `echo %CD%` like this this:

[image]

The Windows Scripting Host provides [the `ExpandEnvironmentalStrings` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf(v=vs.84).aspx) which can be used like this:

```
Dim objWshShell : Set objWshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
MsgBox objWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
```

[image]

However, it doesn't work with `%CD%`.  It just returns the same value, `%CD%`:

```
Dim objWshShell : Set objWshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
MsgBox objWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%CD%")
```

[image]

Why doesn't this work?  I know there are other ways to get the current directory; this is just a curiousity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable `%CD%` is a CMD-builtin automatic variable, not an environment variable like `%PATH%` or `%USERNAME%`. It can only be used within CMD, e.g.

```
cmd /c echo %CD%
```

Same goes for the variables `%TIME%`, `%DATE%`, and `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

If you want the current working directory in VBScript you need to use the [`CurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd.aspx) property of the `WshShell` object

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo sh.CurrentDirectory
```

or [expand the path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1xa64f.aspx) of the directory `.`:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```